# Pip not working on windows 10, freezes command prompt

Tags: python, windows, pip

I recently installed Python for Windows 10 and need to use `pip` command to install the `requests` package.
However, whenever I try to use `pip` in cmd it just freezes my command prompt.

Using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> or any command like that to cancel it does not work either, the prompt just freezes like its waiting for input or something, but I get no output or any clue about what to do.

[image: Picture of command promt when its frozen]

I have set the `PATH` variable correctly, and my computer finds `pip` and launches it, but it just freezes. I have also tried reinstalling Python countless times and manually reinstalling `pip` but nothing seems to do the trick.

Comment: Try `python -m pip install requests` or, if the new launcher is installed, `py -2 -m pip install requests`.

Comment: BTW, `Ctrl+D` (ASCII end-of-transmission, `EOT`) signals end-of-file (`EOF`) for stdin, but only in a Unix terminal. The Windows console doesn't implement anything exactly like this. The closest analog is the `ReadFile` function, which, when reading from the console, treats `Ctrl+Z` (ASCII substitute, `SUB`) at the beginning of a line as `EOF`. Since `ReadFile` has to read a line of input, you have to key `Ctrl+Z, Enter`, while on Unix `Ctrl+D` is handled in the terminal and doesn't require pressing enter.

Comment: I thought I had this problem too; it turns out it was just a _really_ long initialization before the UI updated with downloading. Antivirus might have been the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `easy-install` insted of `pip` it works in the same way.

Answer (score 15):

I had exactly the same problem here (Windows 10.0.10240). After typing just "pip" and hitting enter, nothing else happened on the console. This problem was affecting including other .exe compiled python related scripts like mezzanine-project.exe.

The antivirus AVAST was the culprit (in my case) !!!

After disabling AVAST files module (or uninstalling AVAST) pip started working again.

Comment: can't believe people are advocating disabling AV software when installing packages from a remote host. lolz.

Comment: AVAST is not the only antivirus in the world (lolz). I just replaced it for another one.

Comment: but wouldnt the right path be to email the vendor and say, hey, your software is doing something weird?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I got sick of AVAST but it is not just for me, so I just opened a support ticket with them https://pt.support.avast.com/support/tickets/175186

Comment: think that tickets attached to your login, but will do the same with them. though i think the actual answer lies with @eryksun

Answer (score 4):

i didn't think i had the same issue as @Marcio, but the longer it went on, it turned out i did.

In avast, goto the settings, goto Active PRotection, go to File System Shield and add an exclusion for

```
C:\Python27\Scripts
```

should work without a reboot, did for me, I was having issues with the Virtualenv.exe which is in that folder.

Answer (score 1):

@eryksun provided what I think should be the answer to this question. I also have had the command prompt hang whenever I try to use pip, but I do not want to use `easy_install`. The solution (from @eryksun) was to use `python -m pip install package_name`. This works great for managing python packages in windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Marco's answer worked perfectly but the actual solution to the problem is that you should write your pip commands using `python -m pip` instead of just `pip`
so your command will be `python -m pip install requests`

Comment: If this actually works for you, then its more likely that you've got the folder containing the Python exe on your path, but not the subfolder Scripts.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem with the numpy module. The only way I could fix it is by following the steps found here: [Installing NumPy and SciPy on 64-bit Windows (with Pip)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26657334/installing-numpy-and-scipy-on-64-bit-windows-with-pip)

The steps were to

1. Download the appropriate precompiled wheel from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/
2. Type `pip install /path/to/module.whl`

This worked perfectly for me. Hope this helps anyone else with this exact issue.

Comment: I had the same problem too. It's good to know about the precompiled versions! Not as convenient but better than nothing...

Answer (score 0):

Well, when you run python -m pip, it actually starts pip.exe as a child process, so in the end it freezes the same for me, although it runs a bit longer...
Worse is that the pip.exe process is completely zombie, no way to kill it even with ProcExpl....

Comment: Answers should answer the question, this really just verifies the poster isn't the only one seeing the problem and would be more appropriate as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Just disable your antivirus and it should work.

Comment: disabling your antivirus isn't required, just an exception. plus. its slightly dangerous advice.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@Marco Del Toro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33638718/5446749), using `easy_install` worked for me: I could install the packages I needed for my project. I also managed to fix `pip` using `easy_install` so `pip` also works for me now. The solution to fixing `pip` was: `easy_install pip`.

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/33638395/2) to the question [Pip not working on windows 10, freezes command promt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33638395/pip-not-working-on-windows-10-freezes-command-promt) by the OP [Olof H](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5548094/olof-h) under CC BY-SA 3.0.</sub>

Answer (score -1):

If you have a certain network it can block pip for installation. For my case I used my own network without VPN.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).