# SciPy installation on windows for python 3.5

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to install scipy with different ways but all fails with me

I have windows x64 and python 3.5

I tried to download scipy-0.17.0-cp35-none-win_amd64, scipy-0.17.0-cp35-none-win32, numpy-1.11.0+mkl-cp35-cp35m-win32, numpy_1.11.0_mkl_cp35_cp35m_win_amd64

None of them is installing successfully and I want to fix it. Anyway else than using Anaconda ?

When I try pip install scipy, here is the error I am getting:

```
Collecting scipy
  Using cached scipy-0.17.0.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: scipy
  Running setup.py install for scipy ... error
    Complete output from command c:\python35\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools
, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\****\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-2kjh7_yz
\\scipy\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read()
.replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\*****\App
Data\Local\Temp\pip-tsi_rnlj-record\install-record.txt --single-version-external
ly-managed --compile:
    lapack_opt_info:
    openblas_lapack_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\python35\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\python3
5\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_mkl_info:
    mkl_info:
      libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['c:\\python35\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\py
thon35\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    c:\python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:633: UserWarnin
g: Specified path C:\projects\windows-wheel-builder\atlas-builds\atlas-3.11.38-s
se2-64\lib is invalid.
      warnings.warn('Specified path %s is invalid.' % d)
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_info:
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_info:
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    c:\python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1542: UserWarni
ng:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
    lapack_info:
      libraries lapack not found in ['c:\\python35\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\python35\
\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    c:\python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1553: UserWarni
ng:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.__doc__)
    lapack_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    c:\python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1556: UserWarni
ng:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
      NOT AVAILABLE

    Running from scipy source directory.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-2kjh7_yz\scipy\setup.py
", line 265, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-2kjh7_yz\scipy\setup.py
", line 262, in setup_package
        setup(**metadata)
      File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 135, in
 setup
        config = configuration()
      File "C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-2kjh7_yz\scipy\setup.py
", line 182, in configuration
        config.add_subpackage('scipy')
      File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 10
03, in add_subpackage
        caller_level = 2)
      File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 97
2, in get_subpackage
        caller_level = caller_level + 1)
      File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 90
9, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
        config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
      File "scipy\setup.py", line 15, in configuration
        config.add_subpackage('linalg')
      File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 10
03, in add_subpackage
        caller_level = 2)
      File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 97
2, in get_subpackage
        caller_level = caller_level + 1)
      File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 90
9, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
        config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
      File "scipy\linalg\setup.py", line 20, in configuration
        raise NotFoundError('no lapack/blas resources found')
    numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\python35\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\
\Users\\*****\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-2kjh7_yz\\scipy\\setup.py';exec(
compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'),
__file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-tsi_
rnlj-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" fa
iled with error code 1 in C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-2kjh7_yz\
scipy\
```

Comment: Do yourself a favor and install anaconda

Comment: or use the suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26670308/2776376

Comment: @Ashafix I tried that link but still failed

Comment: weird, worked for me via Gohlke's link.

Answer (score 0):

1.you should uninstall numpy，Using command 'pip uinstall numpy'.
2.reinstall numpy
by command 'pip uninstall+the directory path + numpy_1.11.0_mkl_cp35_cp35m_win_amd64.
3.download VC++ 2015 REDISTRIBUTABLE by microsoft web.install it.
4.install scipy like 2 step

Sorry my english is terrible,I just can help you like this.