# i'm using Python3 ,but I can't install scipy

Tags: python-3.x, scipy

C:\Users\Tina>pip install scipy

Collecting scipy

Using cached scipy-0.18.0.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: scipy
  Running setup.py install for scipy ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\tina\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\Tina\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-05e6tnno\scipy\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Tina\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-qovmh2aa-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:

```
Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:

  - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
                           release)
  - `pip install scipy`   (last SciPy release on PyPI)


lapack_opt_info:
openblas_lapack_info:
  libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\users\\tina\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\tina\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

lapack_mkl_info:
mkl_info:
  libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['c:\\users\\tina\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\tina\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
C:\Users\Tina\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:639: UserWarning: Specified path C:\projects\numpy-wheels\windows-wheel-builder\atlas-builds\atlas-3.11.38-sse2-64\lib is invalid.
  warnings.warn('Specified path %s is invalid.' % d)
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_info:
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_info:
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\Tina\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1548: UserWarning:
    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
    the ATLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
lapack_info:
  libraries lapack not found in ['c:\\users\\tina\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\tina\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\Tina\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1559: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
    the LAPACK environment variable.
  warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.__doc__)
lapack_src_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\Tina\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1562: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
    the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
  warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
  NOT AVAILABLE

Running from scipy source directory.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Tina\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-05e6tnno\scipy\setup.py", line 415, in <module>
    setup_package()
  File "C:\Users\Tina\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-05e6tnno\scipy\setup.py", line 411, in setup_package
    setup(**metadata)
  File "C:\Users\Tina\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 135, in setup
    config = configuration()
  File "C:\Users\Tina\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-05e6tnno\scipy\setup.py", line 335, in configuration
    config.add_subpackage('scipy')
  File "C:\Users\Tina\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1003, in add_subpackage
    caller_level = 2)
  File "C:\Users\Tina\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 972, in get_subpackage
    caller_level = caller_level + 1)
  File "C:\Users\Tina\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 909, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
    config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
  File "scipy\setup.py", line 15, in configuration
    config.add_subpackage('linalg')
  File "C:\Users\Tina\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1003, in add_subpackage
    caller_level = 2)
  File "C:\Users\Tina\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 972, in get_subpackage
    caller_level = caller_level + 1)
  File "C:\Users\Tina\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 909, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
    config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
  File "scipy\linalg\setup.py", line 20, in configuration
    raise NotFoundError('no lapack/blas resources found')
numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found

----------------------------------------
```

Command "c:\users\tina\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\Tina\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-05e6tnno\scipy\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Tina\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-qovmh2aa-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Tina\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-05e6tnno\scipy\

C:\Users\Tina>

Comment: You ought to try Anaconda, https://www.continuum.io/downloads. Everything you need and nothing you don't

Comment: It is likely an issue with a sub-dependency like numpy which relies on an appropriate C compiler.  Currently, Anaconda removes this headache by building these packages for you and including non-Python dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion,but I still want to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using pip3? Since you're using python3, that should work! Look at this page:
[Installing NumPy and SciPy on 64-bit Windows (with Pip)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26657334/installing-numpy-and-scipy-on-64-bit-windows-with-pip)