# Error while installing scipy

Tags: python, scipy, runtime-error

I am getting the following error while installing scipy:pip3 install scipy:

```
Command ""c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;
__file__='C:\\Users\\USERPC~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-2at_hdlt\\scipy\\setup.py';
f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);
code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');
f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\USERPC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-motm11xo-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\USERPC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-illwqsel\scipy\
```

Can anyone please provide any pointers to solve this?

Comment: see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26670308/6338809)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing NumPy and SciPy on 64-bit Windows (with Pip)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26657334/installing-numpy-and-scipy-on-64-bit-windows-with-pip)