# Error Installing SciPy

Tags: python, scipy

I have a windows computer and I tried installing SciPy in the Command Prompt using pip. "Pip install SciPy" this worked for other functions that I have installed; however, for this one it gave me an error. Any help would be great

Below is the Error Code:

> Command
>   "c:\users\wdley\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\python.exe
>   -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\wdley\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-c0h_k6mh\SciPY\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record C:\Users\wdley\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-0i8tdreh-record\install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\wdley\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-c0h_k6mh\SciPY\

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing NumPy and SciPy on 64-bit Windows (with Pip)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26657334/installing-numpy-and-scipy-on-64-bit-windows-with-pip)