# How can I install python module Scipy? I have python3.5 and working on 64-bit windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, scipy

I have pythone3.5 and I am trying to install the Scipy module. I tried **"pip install scipy"** but it shows an error **"numpy.distutils.system_info.NotfoundError: no lapack/blas resources found"**. I also tried to use **"scipy-0.19.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl"** from "http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy" but it also didn't work, it shows **"scipy-0.19.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform"**
What should I do?

Comment: What error does it show? Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26657334/installing-numpy-and-scipy-on-64-bit-windows-with-pip)

Comment: I add them to the post

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pip3.5 install scipy
```