# Simple python library can't install

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, pip

Windows 10 Enterprise version 10.0.1.15063 build 15063. Tried both pip and pip3:

```
pip install scipy
pip3 install scipy
```

Both didn't work. Even tried to specify path of python directory, still didn't work.

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean, in this context? Like... nothing happened? Or there was an error? What was the error message? Or were you expecting them to do something and they did something else? (For future reference "*didn't work*" is just about the worst bug report ever. Don't use this phrase when trying to get help... you'll just make other folks and yourself more frustrated.)

Comment: didn't work => not installed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing NumPy and SciPy on 64-bit Windows (with Pip)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26657334/installing-numpy-and-scipy-on-64-bit-windows-with-pip)

Answer (score -1):

If you're using **Windows**, open **Command Prompt (CMD)** and run this command

```
run python pip -m install [module]
```

OR

```
run py pip -m install [module]
```

Answer (score -2):

Finally installed.
Just updated git and ran the same command again "pip install scipy"
but this time it worked and installed the library.

Comment: I don't understand in what way `git` is related to `pip install`. Can you explain?

Comment: Actually I use git command prompt instead of windows terminal. Windows terminal is not that much strong as git.
You can even use shell of python for this purpose.
Git is basically for 'source code management' but it is very helpful, even resourceful for keeping track of changes in any set of files